# querying netsh in c#

Tags: c#, .net, netsh

I've been trying to come up with an ideal way to query WiFi information using C#. I've tried the `netsh` method but was unsure how to separate the information. I notice that `Vistumbler` uses `netsh`. Is there a way that these developers would have separated the information when querying `netsh` or have they just performed a lot of string manipulation to cut out the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: What kind of information do you need from netsh ?

Comment: @Nacereddine im just trying to get the physical id and rssi of multiple access points. Im using 'Managed WiFi API' but wondered, since Vistumbler uses netsh if that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is what I do usually. Call `netsh`, get the output and parse it.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "netsh arguments...";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// parse output and look for results
```

Comment: This seems like the most functional way, but be aware that the format of the arguments may be slightly different in Vista or in XP.  Open a CMD window and check with **netsh -?** on both OSes to be sure.